# Unable to access class which appears after page click in pupeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, cheerio

I want to access a class that appears after the click, but it seems like I need to wait a few miliseconds before it can be accessed, using a timeout just returns null and I'm not very sure on how we can use async in nested return statements

I am trying to scrape data from google maps listings, I am clicking on every business that is present on the page which in turn opens a popup that shows reviews of the place and that is what I am trying to access, the industry eg - gyms and location eg - new york are being passed from a form in the frontend.

```
async function getLocalPlacesInfo() {
 
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const URL = `https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN1013IN1013&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:4&tbm=lcl&sxsrf=ALiCzsYyOgzRUZVKXVE5RhwFgF8i8FftHA:1665928778589&q=${industry}+in+${location}&rflfq=1&num=10&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8lsao9OT6AhW-3XMBHSZvB5oQjGp6BAgXEAE&biw=1920&bih=1001&dpr=1#rlfi=hd:;si:;`;

  await page.goto(URL);

  const localPlacesInfo = [];
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000); 
   
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000); 

 
    localPlacesInfo.push(...(await fillDataFromPage(page)));
  
  browser.close();
  return localPlacesInfo;
}

async function fillDataFromPage(page) {
  const dataFromPage = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".VkpGBb")).map((el, i) => {
      console.log(el)
      el.querySelector('.OSrXXb')?.click()
   
       //need to wait here, set timeout not working as null gets returned  

      return {
        title: el.querySelector(".OSrXXb")?.textContent.trim(),

        rating: querySelector(".Aq14fc")?.textContent.trim(), // this class appears after click

        address: el.querySelector(".W4Efsd:last-child > .W4Efsd:nth-of-type(1) > span:last-child")?.textContent.replaceAll("·", "").trim(),       
        phone: el.querySelector(".W4Efsd:last-child > .W4Efsd:nth-of-type(3) > span:last-child")?.textContent.replaceAll("·", "").trim(),
        website: el.querySelector(".L48Cpd")?.getAttribute("href"),
      };
    });
  });
  return dataFromPage;
}
```

Comment: to use await I need to make the map function async which the return statement does not wait for and an array of nulls is returned instead

Comment: I have edited the question and added more info

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `setTimeout` inside a `Promise`. `Promise.all` can be used to handle an array of `Promise`s created by mapping over the elements.

```js
return Promise.all(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".VkpGBb")).map(async (el, i) => {
  console.log(el)
  el.querySelector('.OSrXXb')?.click()
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
  return {
    title: el.querySelector(".OSrXXb")?.textContent.trim(),

    rating: querySelector(".Aq14fc")?.textContent.trim(), // this class appears after click

    address: el.querySelector(".W4Efsd:last-child > .W4Efsd:nth-of-type(1) > span:last-child")?.textContent.replaceAll("·", "").trim(),       
    phone: el.querySelector(".W4Efsd:last-child > .W4Efsd:nth-of-type(3) > span:last-child")?.textContent.replaceAll("·", "").trim(),
    website: el.querySelector(".L48Cpd")?.getAttribute("href"),
  };
}));
```

Comment: turns out we cannot access 'page' inside the map function, getting a page is not defined message

Comment: Does not seem to solve the issue, still unable to access the class getting the message - ReferenceError: querySelector is not defined

Comment: @AnshumShailey That's an error in your original code. You should have written `el.querySelector` instead of `querySelector` there.

Comment: The reason for not using el there is that after the click a popup opens which contains the class I want to get, el.query selector will check if the the class is nested inside the click element right?

Comment: @AnshumShailey Then use `document.querySelector`.

Comment: That helped thank you, but the issue is that I'm getting the value of the element that pops up on the click of the last mapped item in all the elements